# CSS - Position outside div absolute relative to another

Tags: html, css

As an example, if I had a simple layout that looked like this...

```css
.outside_element {
height:50px;
width:100px;
text-align:center;
background:red;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside_element">
  Outside Content
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mycontent">
    <p>
      This is some example content
    </p>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

But I had no control over the output of the HTML, outside_element is always output outside of the rest of my content. Is there a way to position outside_element realtive to .mycontent?

Event though outside_element is not within that div?

Can I achieve this using CSS alone, or do I need to do some javascript to move it first?

Comment: I am not clear about your question. Can you explain better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, we make `outside_element` a child of `mycontent`.
**Next**, we set the `position` of each element. `outside_element` should have the `position:absolute;` while `mycontent` will have the `position:relative`. **Lastly**, we adjust the left, right,top,or bottom attribute to adjust its physical position. Hope this helps :)

**About your second question:** You need to put your `outside_element` inside `mycontent` because it will look for a parent element that has a `position:relative` and make that the reference.

```css
.outside_element {
height:50px;
width:100px;
text-align:center;
background:red;
color:white;
position: absolute;

top: 0%;
right:0%;

}

.mycontent{
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mycontent">
    <div class="outside_element">
      Outside Content
    </div>
    <p>
      This is some example content
    </p>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to absolutely position an element relatively to one another (this sentence makes sense only when it's about CSS I guess...), you can set the CSS rule `position:relative` to the reference element:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="relative-box">
  <p>
    Hi all
  </p>
  <div class="absolute-box">
    Yes!
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
div.relative-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 5em;
  width: 10em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #808080;
}
    
div.absolute-box {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0em;
  bottom: 0em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/on91jLrb/)

Answer (score -1):

Move outside-element inside wrapper or mycontent.

Give `position:relative` to 'wrapper' or 'mycontent' and `position:absolute` to 'outside-element'.

If it doesn't work, let me know.